# Can an electric current's magnetic field be represented by a magnet/magnets?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields

Is it possible to recreate the exact same magnetic field that electric currents have with a magnet and if it is, how?

Comment: You should be more specific with the question. If you speak about a thin wire wildly positioned in space, I would say no. But if you speak about mimicking a simple coil mg. field, why not?

Comment: the electric current will be a completed loop for the current to be able to flow.  are you wanting the same m. field **shape**?

Answer (score 1):

Wow. Nice question.

The short answer is YES.

The long answer is complicated, but begins with Relativity. The general gist of it is that the magnetic field is a force that exists so that the electric force works in all frames of reference.

In other words, if you move a magnetic field, you get an electric field. When you move an electric field, you get a magnetic field.